# Is it possible to set a Virtual Directory as Root Directory in IIS 7?

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic, windows-server-2008

Is it possible to setup the Virtual Directory or Application so the entailing code see's the Application or Virtual Dir. as a root (/) ?

Answer (score 3):

Since that original "Root" is no longer useful just change the root physical folder to be your applications physical root folder.  Your app becomes the root of the site.